# MS Access - Use of the Multiselection in a Query

Tags: ms-access

I use this formula to get the variables from a multiselection combo box:

```
Function ReturnMultiSelection() As String
Dim i As Variant
Dim ctl As Control

Set ctl = [Forms]![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![fActivity]
   For Each i In ctl.ItemsSelected
         ReturnMultiSelection = ctl.ItemData(i) & "," & ReturnMultiSelection
   Next i

ReturnMultiSelection = "IN (" & ReturnMultiSelection & ")"
End Function
```

this formula works without problem in a SQL VBA code, but if I use in a query criteria return the error: "Data Type Mismatch in Criteria expression"

```
SELECT Q_AVG_Compact_Manhours.Skill_ID
FROM Q_AVG_Compact_Manhours
WHERE (((Q_AVG_Compact_Manhours.Skill_ID)=ReturnMultiSelection()));
```

Where I wrong? Thanks a lot for the help ;)

Comment: Sorry, array list for IN() function cannot be dynamic in a query object. It's sad but true. Would have to use QueryDefs to modify query object. You said this is a multi-select combobox but did you mean a multi-select listbox? What you can do is set RecordSource property with this SQL statement. That is simple for a form but gets tricky for a report.

Comment: Not really a surprise, since what you have evaluates to Skill_id= " in (34,534,23)". So you have to concat the string and feed that to the data engine. however, you can certainly send that criteria to a report as a where clause. "Skill_id  " & returnMultiseleciton. So you do NOT need to build a query that includes the above. Base the report on a query, and then use above expression as a where clause when you open the report via docmd.openReport and use above expression for the where clause of the open report command. The result is a filter on the report anyway.

Comment: Thanks a Lot. I'm really noob and I'm not familiar with SQL code, so I don't use.
In this case, with the modification directly on SQL, (not trough MSQuery) it work!

Thanks again for the precious help.